# FILTRO de PRODUCTOS para tienda o ecommerce!

Tags: javascript, html, filtro

Tengo en HTML un:

```
<select id="filtro">
    <option value="all">Todos</option>
    <option value="Pintura">Pintura</option>
    <option value="Acuarela">Acuarela</option>
    <option value="Dibujo">Dibujo</option>
    <option value="Esculturas">Esculturas</option>
</select>
```

EL cual quiero filtrar el `stockProductos` para que al hacer click filtre por su tipo
Empece haciendo esto para llamar al id="filtro"
// Filtrado de productos:

```
let miFiltro = document.getElementById("filtro");
miFiltro.EventListener("change", filtrado);
function filtrado(){
    function mostrar ()
    stockProductos.forEach(producto => producto.tipo.includes(miFiltro.value))
}
```

Probe mil formas y estoy haciendo algo mal !!!!!!!!!!!
el stock es = stockProductos y los productos filtrados con= producto.tipo
Espero que me puedan ayudar MIL GRACIAAAAAAAAS

Comment: No se que editor usas ni como depuras la sintaxis, pero lo que yo veo son errores de sintaxis básicos de momento. Si las mil formas en que lo has probado han sido basándote en esto como código base esta claro que no te han funcionado por la sintaxis. Coge y pega ese código en https://jsfiddle.net, revisa los puntos rojos (que indican errores de sintaxis) y los errores en console (abre la `console (beta)`) que te aparezcan, y cuando ya lo tengas arreglado, si aun tienes problemas, [edit] esta pregunta poniendo código sin errores de sintaxis, explicando el problema y podremos mirar de ayudarte.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Podrías usar la función .filter() para filtrar un arreglo. Te devolverá los elementos que cumplan la condición que creas conveniente.